# Can't set onClick useing material-calendarview from github project

Tags: android, android-calendar

I take the reference from https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

I implements `OnDateSelectedListener` and `@Override onDateSelected` , but there is no working when i clcik any days on calendar .

Why?

Any one can teach me the point what do i miss ? Thanks in advance

gradle project:

```
compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'
```

Layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.testcalendar0420_1.MainActivity">

    <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:mcv_showOtherDates="all"
        app:mcv_selectionColor="#00F"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My calendar class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnDateSelectedListener {

    private MaterialCalendarView calendarView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //I can see the calendar on screen
        calendarView = (MaterialCalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);

        System.out.println("onCreate");

    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSelected(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView widget, @NonNull CalendarDay date, boolean selected) {
        //selected is no value on logcat
        Log.d("selected", "" + selected);
        //It can't be show
        Toast.makeText(this, "enterDateSelected" + date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (selected == true) {
            //It can't be show
            Toast.makeText(this, "onClick" + date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not setting the listener to the MaterialCalendarView, to solve it you must add this to the `onCreate` after the view initialization:

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(this);
```

Comment: Holy...how can i miss the code , you save my life , thank you.